# android - google sign in always request

Tags: android, google-signin

how to user open app without signin always, when user not logout.. I'm already using sharedpreff but still request login

this code for login

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.toString());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String nama = acct.getDisplayName();
            String email = acct.getEmail();
            String id = acct.getId();
            String foto = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());

            session.createLoginSession(id,nama,email,foto);
            SharedPrefApp sharedPref;
            sharedPref = SharedPrefApp.getInstance();

            sharedPref.saveISLogged_IN(this, true);//add this on user sucessful login

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WelcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0), "GAGAL LOGIN", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me!

```
mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Make sure mGoogleApiClient not null